# Spring Rest:filter api with multile parameters

Tags: java, api, spring-boot

I am implementing a filter endpoint and I want my URL to be something like

> api/search?property=name&value=raj,peter&filter[birthDate]=2018-02-16&filter[state]=xxx

where filter will be a POJO and birthDate and state will be its fields(properties for filtering).I am not getting how to get the URL of this format.

I tried passing birthDate and state as queryParameter and mapping these to a POJO.But in this case the URL is of format:

> api/search?property=name&value=raj,peter&birthDate=2018-02-16&state=xxx

expected URL format:

> api/search?property=name&value=raj,peter&filter[birthDate]=2018-02-16&filter[state]=xxx

actual format:

> api/search?property=name&value=raj,peter&birthDate=2018-02-16&state=xxx

Comment: POST for passing body in request

Comment: It is a GET method

Comment: Check out https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt (search for "unsafe").  Putting `[...]` in your url violates the requirement of 'these must always be encoded'.  I'd reconsider your desired URL format if I were you.

Comment: Yes I have checked this out.But this format is needed